# If statement accessing data in another workbook in excel-vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to program a macro.

- I am writing the macro in a new black workbook (this is part of the requirement) and I have a lot of data in a different workbook.
- I need to use the macro to read the data in that different workbook and spit out errors encountered for each column and write it in the blank workbook (that i am programming macro in).
- So for each column it's suppose to have list of row numbers an error was encountered (and nothing else). I'm trying to write an If statement to do this and i keep getting an error message stating "expected then or go to".

This is what I have so far:

`If [Dataset1.xls]Data1!R2C1=53 AND [Dataset1.xls]Data1!R2C1=453 AND [Dataset1.xls]Data1!R2C1=953 Then`

The dataset1.xls is the workbook that holds all the data and Data1 is the sheet in that workbook with all the data. I might be accessing the separate workbook totally wrong. Can you guys please help. Thank you very much in advance.

This is most of the code:

```
Dim numrow As Long
Dim count As Long
count = 2

With Workbooks("Dataset1.xls").Sheets("Data1")
numrow = .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.count

End With
Do Until count = numrow
If [Dataset1.xls]Data1!R2C1<>53 AND [Dataset1.xls]Data1!R2C1<>453 AND [Dataset1.xls]Data1!R2C1<>953 Then  

End If
count = count + 1
Loop
```

Comment: have you tried first to access the workbook without any validation ? just read some cell in there

Comment: Yes i have tried to. I was able to successfully count the number of rows with data the worksheet had.

Comment: Could you post that part of the code ?

Comment: Sure let me edit my post above and put the entire code

Comment: Your if doesn't make sense. You're checking to see if the same cell is simultaneously equaling three different values. Furthermore it ignores the count variable that you're incrementing. You should do something like `Workbooks("Dataset1.xls").Sheets("Data1").Cells(count, 1)`

Comment: About the if statement, yes you are right. I accidentally put = instead of <>. Also I'll try to incorporate that piece of code and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change

```
If Workbooks("Dataset1.xls").Sheets("Data1").Cells(2, 1).Value <> 53 AND Workbooks("Dataset1.xls").Sheets("Data1").Cells(2, 1).Value <> 453 AND Workbooks("Dataset1.xls").Sheets("Data1").Cells(2, 1).Value <> 953 Then
```

Instead of:

```
If [Dataset1.xls]Data1!R2C1<>53 AND [Dataset1.xls]Data1!R2C1<>453 AND [Dataset1.xls]Data1!R2C1<>953 Then
```

Regards

-- full code:

```
range = Workbooks("Dataset1.xls").Worksheets("Data").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To range

If Workbooks("Dataset1.xls").Sheets("Data1").Cells(i, 1).Value <> 53 AND Workbooks("Dataset1.xls").Sheets("Data1").Cells(i, 1).Value <> 453 AND Workbooks("Dataset1.xls").Sheets("Data1").Cells(i, 1).Value <> 953 Then

End IF

Next i
```

Comment: Ok i was making a stupid mistake. That code is flawless. Thank you very much. You saved me so much trouble.